# raspberry pi specific script to run commands upon cpu reaching defined temperature

Tags: raspberry-pi, cpu

i just need certain commands (that control fans and light up a warning LED) to be run when cpu temperature exceeds a certain threshold and other scripts if and when they finally return to below another specified temperature

i want multiple temperatures defined, like if the cpu exceeds 50 celsius to turn on the fan via a relay switch, but if less than 45 to turn the fan off, 60 to turn on a warning LED less than 55 to turn that LED off and if it reaches 80 to shutdown completely. any ideas? i use dietpi on a rpi 3b so raspian exclusive methods will not work. also how to run this as a system service

Comment: What have you tried so far? Monitoring CPU temperature on the Pi is already well documented (see e.g. [this article](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2020/11/raspberry-pi-temperature-monitoring/)). There are lots of examples here and on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com that would show you how to create a system service.

Comment: i should learn not to delete something right away just because it doesn't work. i had a python script that used an if condition, the syntax needed to achieve this task in python, or bash is what i need, i'm not a very skilled coder admittedly, let me look over this link you've sent!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find someone to cobble something together for me, I'm going to put what she did here so others can learn if need be.

I'll replace these `echo` commands with the actual commands in production but meanwhile enjoy my snarky replies from the computer

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#CPU Temp

from gpiozero import CPUTemperature
cpu = CPUTemperature()
temp = (cpu.temperature)

#Commands Section

if temp <= 50:
 import subprocess
 subprocess.run(["echo", "Coolishness!"])

elif temp >= 60 and temp <= 69:
 import subprocess
 subprocess.run(["echo","a wee bit toasty innit?"])

elif temp >= 70 and temp <= 79:
 import subprocess
 subprocess.run(["echo","do computers sweat?"])

elif temp >= 90:
 import subprocess
 subprocess.run(["echo","gawd the smell of burning silicon, it does things for me"])
```